# Jquery Delay Between Keyup Functions

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

I have a bit of code that i am writing, trying to intergrate bing search API in my site with instant search results.  I use jquery's keyup function to send the data to my server side script which then gets the bing search xml and shows the results.

The worry i have is that i will be making way too many unncessary hits to my scripts.
Can someone please look at this and tell me how i can put a 1 second delay between keyups as a timer?  so it will only update the reults every one seconds or so?

THis is what i have created so far, but i dont know if its correct???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var delay = (function() {

    var timer = 0;

    return function(callback, ms) {

        clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);

    };

})();



function reloadsearch() {
    var searchterms = $('#q').val();
    if (searchterms.length >= 3) {
        delay(function() {
            var data = 'source=ajax&q=' + searchterms;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "results/",
                data: data,
                success: function(html) {
                    if (html !== '') {
                        $("#search-results").html(html);
                        $("#search-results").fadeIn(500);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 250);
    }

    else

    {
        $("#search-results").fadeOut(250);
    }
};



$('#q').keyup(function() {
    reloadsearch()
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    reloadsearch()
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of an input box taking input and searching at a slower rate that typing.

http://jsbin.com/ebela4/8/edit

This example doesn't do the ajax piece, but you will get the idea. Try typing in the input box as fast as you can. It will update the search box at a delayed rate. It remembers that the state is 'dirty' and then refreshes if necessary.

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Thank You, You are a Gangsta!

Comment: I'll add that to my bio. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will be doing something like this

```
    var delay = false;
$('#q').keyup(function() {

if(!delay){
    delay = true;
    reloadsearch().delay(1000);
    delay = false;
});
```

logically it should work but i haven't give a try! the syntex might need some changes.

and here is the peace code of code that will help you with this hopefully ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function reloadsearch() {
    var searchterms = $('#q').val();
    if (searchterms.length >= 3) {

            var data = 'source=ajax&q=' + searchterms;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "results/",
                data: data,
                success: function(html) {
                    if (html !== '') {
                        $("#search-results").html(html);
                        $("#search-results").fadeIn(500);
                    }
                }
            });
       }

    else

    {
        $("#search-results").fadeOut(250);
    }
};

var delayOn = false;
$("#test").click(function(){
if(!delayOn){
delayOn = true;
reloadsearch().delay(2000).queue(function(){delayOn = false;$(this).dequeue();});
        }
                  });
                 });
```

Comment: how do i put that in my existing code? Sorry im not that bright... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that is similar to google's search. It won't search until after the user has paused typing.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNX5q/